# Unexpected bash quoting behaviour

Tags: bash

I have a pipeline of bash commands that looks like this:

```
cat report.json | \
./jq '.outdated.dependencies[] |  {group, name, "version": .available.milestone} | .group + ":" + .name + ":" + .version' | \
xargs -0 -d'\n' -I DEPENDENCY echo ./gradlew clean test -PdependencyOverrides=DEPENDENCY
```

The output of this command is:

```
./gradlew clean test -PdependencyOverrides="org.flywaydb:flyway-core:4.0.3"
./gradlew clean test -PdependencyOverrides="org.hibernate:hibernate-c3p0:5.2.5.Final"
./gradlew clean test -PdependencyOverrides="org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.2.5.Final"
./gradlew clean test -PdependencyOverrides="org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:5.2.5.Final"
./gradlew clean test -PdependencyOverrides="org.hibernate:hibernate-java8:5.2.5.Final"
./gradlew clean test -PdependencyOverrides="org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.3.3.Final"
./gradlew clean test -PdependencyOverrides="com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.5"
./gradlew clean test -PdependencyOverrides="com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.8.5"
./gradlew clean test -PdependencyOverrides="javax.el:javax.el-api:3.0.1-b04"
./gradlew clean test -PdependencyOverrides="org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.7"
./gradlew clean test -PdependencyOverrides="org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.7"
./gradlew clean test -PdependencyOverrides="org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.7"
./gradlew clean test -PdependencyOverrides="org.mockito:mockito-core:2.2.28"
./gradlew clean test -PdependencyOverrides="org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4.1212"
./gradlew clean test -PdependencyOverrides="com.getsentry.raven:raven-log4j2:7.8.1"
./gradlew clean test -PdependencyOverrides="com.sparkjava:spark-core:2.5.4"
./gradlew clean test -PdependencyOverrides="org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.3.4.RELEASE"
./gradlew clean test -PdependencyOverrides="org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-restassured:1.1.2.RELEASE"
```

This is exactly what I am expecting. If I copy and paste one of these commands, they do exactly what I want them to do. Now I don't want to print these commands but directly execute them. However, as soon as I remove the `echo` from the `xargs` command, it doesn't work. "It doesn't work" means that the property is not correctly passed to gradle.

In order to debug this issue, I tried to append `| bash -x` to my pipeline which revealed the issue but I don't know how to solve it.
Appending this yields the following output as the first line:

```
+ ./gradlew clean test $'-PdependencyOverrides=org.flywaydb:flyway-core:4.0.3\r'
```

I assume, the problem is that `bash` for some reason I don't know puts the arguments in quotes and prepends them with `$`. If I execute the command exactly as it is printed here, the same error occurs as if I let `xargs` directly run the command.

**What do I have to change so the commands are executed exactly the way they are printed when I add the `echo` to the `xargs` command?**

[Here](http://pastebin.com/cNRWT6TA) is the `report.json` file if anyone wants to reproduce this locally and `jq` can be downloaded [here](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

Gradle is not needed to reproduce this problem, as executing the command in a folder without a `gradlew` file just yields:

```
+ ./gradlew clean test $'-PdependencyOverrides=org.flywaydb:flyway-core:4.0.3\r'
bash: line 1: ./gradlew: No such file or directory
```

which still demonstrates the problem.

I am not sure what the exact problem is, so if there is a better title feel free to change it.

Comment: note the `\r` char. You should try a dos2unix on your input file.

Comment: You are right! Removing the `\r` from the command allows it to execute properly.

Comment: the "puts the arguments in quotes and prepends them with $." is a debugging output from the shell. (ksh does the same). The shell has to normalize all dbl-quoted, single-quoted strings, variables, cmd-substitution ouput", This is just a way of displaying what is the result of variables, cmd-sub, single & dbl quoted strings.  The `\r` is suspicious to me too ;-) . Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the `\r`, removing that did the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`$''` is a valid way of quoting strings in Bash](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes). It's being used because `xtrace` escapes strings if necessary to print the exact command which was run. You get the same kind of result if you try to `printf '%q\n' "$something"`, where `something` contains special characters like newline, tab, backspace, etc.

`\r` won't be visible when you look at output in some editor/terminal which does not escape special characters. For example, if you open a file with `\r` at the end of lines it will simply show `[dos]` at the bottom of the window to indicate that the line separator is `\r\n` (DOS/Windows standard) rather than `\n` (*nix standard).